# How in Ruby can I get the module in which a module instance method is defined?

Tags: ruby, module

Assuming I have:

```
module X::Y::Z::M
  def foo
  end
end
```

How in foo can I dynamically determine the module X::Y::Z::M in the `foo` method? `self.class` will not work because it will evaluate to the class that includes the module.

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"? If you don't want to take the current class into account, you could simply refer to it (statically) as `X::Y::Z::M`. I don't see how this value could possibly change. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Stefan, it is true that I can accomplish the same thing by just using the literal module name X::Y::Z::M. I am doing this across many modules and was hoping for a single consistent representation. In addition, the module names in question have very long names so this makes it more likely the statement will fit on a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Module.nesting` method which returns an array of nesting modules, Refer [nesting method of Moudle](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Module.html#method-c-nesting)

```
module X::Y::Z::M
  def foo
    Module.nesting.first
  end
end
```

Comment: You're on the right track but you need to define module `X`, then module `Y` within `X` and so on. Then define `class C; include X::Y::Z::M; end`, then `C.new.foo`.

Comment: Thanks, Cory. My original question contained the X::Y::Z::M notation, so I think it was reasonable for Supriya to assume that I had defined the module correctly elsewhere, no?

Comment: ...or state that you've assumed `X::Y::Z::M` has already been defined, but you still need to show `foo` being invoked on an instance of a class that has included `X::Y::Z::M`,

Comment: Right, I thought `X::Y::Z::M` has defined already

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you mean given an instance of a class that includes the module, how to determine where that method is defined

Suppose you have,

```
# assuming that you have already defined the modules
module X::Y::Z::M
  def foo
  end
end
```

and another class

```
class Test
  include X::Y::Z::M
end
```

If you want to know where a method is declared you can do

```
Test.new.method(:foo).owner #returns X::Y::Z::M
```

You can also determine this from within `foo`, in case you cannot hardcode it

```
module X::Y::Z::M
 def foo
   method(__method__).owner #this will evaluate to X::Y::Z::M
 end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Ankit. Your answer and Supriya's answer were both very helpful. If I could mark both as accepted answers I would. I marked Supriya's because he is apparently just starting out with only 141 points.